# Binary representation of a natural number

Tags: binary, representation

To get a binary representation from a natural number like 20, we divide this number  by 2 and so on until we cannot divide by 2 anymore. To get a binary representation from a decimal number like 0.4512, we  multiply this number by 2 repeated times.

What is the logic explanation why with these two systems we get a binary representation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the fact that numbers are coded in binary.

If the number A is an integer, A is rewritten as A=∑<sub><sub>i=0</sub></sub><sup><sup>n-1</sup></sup>a<sub>i</sub>×2<sup>i</sup>=a<sub>n-1</sub>×2<sup>n-1</sup>+a<sub>n-2</sub>×2<sup>n-2</sup>+...+a<sub>1</sub>×2+a<sub>0</sub>

where a<sub>i</sub>=0 or 1.

It is easy to see that is A is even, a<sub>0</sub>=0, and if it is odd, a<sub>0</sub>=1. So we already have the least significant bit a<sub>0</sub>.

Now, if we divide A by two, a<sub>0</sub> disappears and we have 
A/2=a<sub>n-1</sub>×2<sup>n-2</sup>+a<sub>n-2</sub>×2<sup>n-3</sup>+...+a<sub>2</sub>×2+a<sub>1</sub>

We can determine this way a<sub>1</sub> depending on the parity of A/2. and we continue, we get all the bits of A.

Fractional numbers are expressed according to negative powers of 2. If A=0.a<sub>-1</sub>a<sub>-2</sub>...a<sub>-n</sub>, A=a<sub>-1</sub>/2+a<sub>-2</sub>/4+...+a<sub>-n</sub>/2^<sup>n</sup>

If we multiply it by two, 2×A=a<sub>-1</sub>+a<sub>-2</sub>/2+...+a<sub>-n</sub>/2^<sup>n-1</sup>. If 2×A≥1, we must have a-1=1, otherwise a-1=0.  And we can determine other bits is a similar way by successive multiplications by two.